# Decode H264 video using libavcodec, C

Tags: c, gcc, ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec

I'm trying to decode a raw h264 file with ffmpeg/libavcodec, but can't get it to work properly. Output should be a raw YUV-File for now. It's possible to compile the code with GCC

```
gcc -o decoder decoder.c -L./lib/ -llibavcodec -llibavutil
```

avcodec.dll, avutil.dll and swresample.dll must be placed in the directory for the .exe to start. Output in the CMD looks like this (only part of it, but its always like this):

```
[h264 @ 00a80f20] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 00a80f20] Missing reference picture, default is 65562
[h264 @ 00a80f20] error while decoding MB 80 54, bytestream -10
[h264 @ 00a80f20] concealing 1649 DC, 1649 AC, 1649 MV errors in B frame
[h264 @ 00a80f20] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 00a80f20] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 00a80f20] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 00a80f20] Missing reference picture, default is 65566
[h264 @ 00a80f20] Missing reference picture, default is 65566
[h264 @ 00a80f20] Missing reference picture, default is 65566
[h264 @ 00a80f20] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 00a80f20] Missing reference picture, default is 65568
[h264 @ 00a80f20] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 00a80f20] Missing reference picture, default is 65570
[h264 @ 00a80f20] reference picture missing during reorder
```

Heres my code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef HAVE_AV_CONFIG_H
#undef HAVE_AV_CONFIG_H
#endif

#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
//#include "libavcodec/libavutil/mathematics.h"

#define INBUF_SIZE 4096

void video_decode(char *outfilename, char *filename)
{
    AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
    int frame, got_picture, len;
    FILE *f, *outf;
    AVFrame *picture;
    uint8_t inbuf[INBUF_SIZE + FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE];
    AVPacket avpkt;
    int i;

    av_init_packet(&avpkt);

    memset(inbuf + INBUF_SIZE, 0, FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);

    codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "codec not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    picture = av_frame_alloc();

    if((codec->capabilities)&CODEC_CAP_TRUNCATED)
        (c->flags) |= CODEC_FLAG_TRUNCATED;

    c->height = 1080;
    c->width = 1920;

    if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    outf = fopen(outfilename,"w");
    if(!outf){
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    frame = 0;
    for(;;) {
        avpkt.size = fread(inbuf, 1, INBUF_SIZE, f);
        if (avpkt.size == 0)
            break;

        avpkt.data = inbuf;
        while (avpkt.size > 0) {

            len = avcodec_decode_video2(c, picture, &got_picture, &avpkt);

            if (len < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error while decoding frame %d\n", frame);
                exit(1);
            }
            if (got_picture) {
                printf("saving frame %3d\n", frame);
                fflush(stdout);
                for(i=0; i<c->height; i++)
                    fwrite(picture->data[0] + i * picture->linesize[0], 1, c->width, outf  );
                for(i=0; i<c->height/2; i++)
                    fwrite(picture->data[1] + i * picture->linesize[1], 1, c->width/2, outf );
                for(i=0; i<c->height/2; i++)
                    fwrite(picture->data[2] + i * picture->linesize[2], 1, c->width/2, outf );
                frame++;
            }
            avpkt.size -= len;
            avpkt.data += len;
        }
    }

    avpkt.data = NULL;
    avpkt.size = 0;
    len = avcodec_decode_video2(c,picture, &got_picture, &avpkt);
    if(got_picture) {
        printf("saving last frame %d\n",frame);
        fflush(stdout);
        for(i=0; i<c->height; i++)
            fwrite(picture->data[0] + i * picture->linesize[0], 1, c->width, outf );
        for(i=0; i<c->height/2; i++)
            fwrite(picture->data[1] + i * picture->linesize[1], 1, c->width/2, outf );
        for(i=0; i<c->height/2; i++)
            fwrite(picture->data[2] + i * picture->linesize[2], 1, c->width/2, outf );
        frame++;
    }

    fclose(f);
    fclose(outf);

    avcodec_close(c);
    av_free(c);
    av_frame_free(&picture);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    avcodec_register_all();
    video_decode("test", "trailer.264");

    return 0;
}
```

I also tried different videos in different formats (of course i changed the codec in the code in this case) like MPEG1, H263, H265, but none of those was working properly either.
I hope someone can help me with this and tell me what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks

Comment: just for info: since at least year 2017, in the sample code provided in the question, FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE must be replaced with AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE (or it will not even compile)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every input packet (avpkt) for avcodec_decode_video2 should contain full (and only) data for one frame i.e. it shouldn't be truncated in the middle of the frame NALs. So your code that reads and sends data in 4096 byte chunks wouldn't work. You need to packetize it yourself by parsing Annex B data and finding start codes and analyzing NAL types (even more in case of frame having more than 1 slice) or use libavformat parser for H.264. As workaround for H.264 you can try to use CODEC_FLAG2_CHUNKS flag but I am not sure how reliable it is and still think 4096-byte chunks are too small.

Comment: I tried using the CODEC_FLAG2_CHUNKS with 128k chunks, but it still won't work. How would I have to use libavformat to get the chunks parsed into single frames? Or would it be easier to packetize the data by myself? Thanks.

Comment: To use libavformat you will need to open your file with avformat_open_input() which can guess format or you can specify it than read packets with av_read_frame() and send packet from needed stream to decoder after which you close file with avformat_close_input(). You may also need avformat_find_stream_info() to get dimensions for decoder and av_find_best_stream() to find needed AVPacket.stream_index corresponding to video stream (if container have more than 1 stream). For more information read avformat.h comments in Demuxing group.

Comment: I played a little with my h264-file (x264 encode) and tried reading out the NALs. I think it worked, i read the first 120, i find start codes (00 00 00 01), the first NAL is followed by 67, the second one by 68, all others by 01 or 41.01 belongs to b-frames, 41 to p-frames? How do I know which NALs belong to a frame? Why are threre no I-Frames? Thanks

Comment: First byte after NAL startcode represents fields: forbidden_zero_bit f(1), nal_ref_idc u(2), nal_unit_type u(5). And so 0x67 mean nal_ref_idc=3 (the highest priority) and nal_unit_type=7 (SPS). 0x67 mean nal_ref_idc=3 and nal_unit_type=8 (PPS). 0x01 mean nal_ref_idc=0 (disposable/non-reference priority) and nal_unit_type=1 (non-IDR slice). 0x41 mean nal_ref_idc=2 (high/reference priority) and nal_unit_type=1 (non-IDR slice). I would recommend you to use libavformat as you already use libavcodec instead of manual parsing because it not so easy to find frame bounds instead of simple NALs bounds.